# oci_bind_by_name doesn't work with LIKE clause

Tags: bind, sql-like, oracle-call-interface

My code is something like this:

```
$s = ociparse($conn, "SELECT u.email, u.city FROM tickets t, users u WHERE t.userId = u.userId AND u.city LIKE '%:city%'");
$city = $_GET['city'];
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":city", $city);
```

Apparently, it can't replace the ":city"

The warning I get:

> Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpOracle\tickets.php on line 41

Comment: bind variable is NOT part of string literal. `SELECT u.email, u.city FROM tickets t, users u WHERE t.userId = u.userId AND u.city LIKE :city;`

Comment: yes, I tryed this too but I want it to work like a regex...  anything before...myString...anything after

Comment: Try `ELECT u.email, u.city FROM tickets t, users u WHERE t.userId = u.userId AND u.city LIKE '%' || :city || '%'; `

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind it like this, you have to concatenate the % signs with it and you cannot have your bound variable wrapped in single quotes:

```
$s = ociparse($conn, "SELECT u.email, u.city FROM tickets t, users u WHERE t.userId = u.userId AND u.city LIKE '%' || :city || '%'");
```